# Upper-Bound/Lower-Bound Inferences and fixing

Tags: c#

In the C# 4.0 Spec 7.5.2.9:

> A *lower-bound inference* from a type U to a type V is made as
>   follows:

- If V is one of the unfixed X<sub>i</sub>, then U is added to the set of lower bounds for X<sub>i</sub>.
- [...]

I've gone over this section many times.  Lacking a section reference, this definition reads like a circular reference.  So, I expect to find a grammer production or section reference nearby to clarify..which I do not.  This section also ties in *Fixing* which suffers from similar definition issues.

What is an `upper-bound inference` vs a `lower-bound inference`?

Comment: I don't think you can take 7.5.2.9 in isolation. You have to take on the entirety of 7.5.2 to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - That's kind-a what I'm afraid of.  It feels like a badly written program.  I have to understand the whole thing just to deal with 1 subsection.  I have read through 7.5.2...but there's so much to juggle in my head Xi Xj, U, V, the assumed Generic.....

Comment: 7.5.2.9 doesn't really define what a lower-bound inference **is**. It's a set of instructions for what you're meant to do when you find (anywhere in 7.5.2) an instruction of e.g. "a lower-bound inference is made from U to T". And then 7.5.2.11 tells you **how** these inferences are used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try my best to describe it more clearly.  Worst case, I describe it *differently*.

The upper/lower inference is one part of a phased approach to type inference with regard to type arguments  that are used for a particular generic method call.  Obviously, upper/lower inference won't be applied if in the first phase if the argument (E) is explicitly typed.  e.g.:

given

```
public static T Choose<T>(T first, T second) {
        return (rand.Next(2) == 0)? first: second;
    }
```

I can invoke `Choose` with explicit type arguments:

```
Choose<String>("first", "second");
```

With regard to the upper- or lower-bounds inference, there are some implications throughout 7.5.2 that decide whether lower- or upper-bounds inference is even applicable.  For example, 7.5.2.9 (and .10) detail that the type parameter is *unfixed* for either upper- or lower-bounds inference to occur.  7.5.2.5 details that a type parameter is only unfixed when that type parameter depends on another unfixed type parameter.  For example

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> e,
    Func<TSource, Result> f)
```

`TResult` "depends on" `TSource`, because the type of `TSource` could possibly determine the type of `TResult`.  e.g. with a call like `Select(c, e->Name)`, `TResult` depends on the type of `Name` in `TSource`.

In terms of upper- and lower-bounds inferences, for a given unfixed type parameter (X) whose type (V) is not explicitly declared (see first paragraph), upper *or* lower bounds of type argument (E) of type U are deduced.  If the type parameter is covariant (has `out` modifier) and one of the types in the lower-bound set is a candidate for the parameter, then a lower-bound inference occurred.  Conversely, if the type parameter is contravariant (has 'in' modifier) and one of the types in the upper-bound set is a candidate for the parameter, then an upper-bound inference occurred.  e.g. with `Select(c, e->e.Name)` and `c` was `IEnumerable<Mammal>` then the compiler would infer an **lower** bound of `Mammal` because the type parameter in `IEnumerable` is covariant (e.g. it's declared `IEnumerable<out T>`.  If it were declared `IEnumerable<in T>` then an upper-bound would be inferred.  And if it were declared `Enumerabale<T>`--with no `in` or `out` then it would be *invariant* and neither upper- nor lower-bounds inference would apply.)

Clearly, if parameter type can be neither covariant nor contravariant then an exact match must occur

Comment: How the hell do you know this!?

Comment: Great explanation Peter.